# How to display the HTTP response status code and the title of the web page at the top of the browser’s main window C# web browser from this code

Tags: c#, web, browser

How to display the HTTP response status code and (if applicable) the title of the web page at the top of the browser’s main window and can anyone explain this code along with?

//C# web browser
string urlAddress = "http://google.com";

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The Status code should be straighforward, you are already checking it at your `if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)`. The title, well you need to extract it from your `string data` variable.

Comment: Your question lacks a bit of information, you mention a web browser but provide no information on what "_the browser’s main window_" is.

Comment: Am creating webbrowser without using C# webbrowser class. For eg if enter url search google.com it will come content page like <!DOctype HTML> etc.